# how can I apply the index to all objects at once?

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

[image]

Hi
how can I apply the index to all objects at once? I want to remove some faces from many cubes at once. Now this is happening in order 1.2,3,4, etc. I want to leave the upper and side face of all cubes at once.
Thank you))

[image]

Comment: Hi, Andrey Re. Unfortunately it's not clear what you mean exactly from what you have written as far. Could you edit the question and explain the situation in more detail providing more context? Why do you need to remove those faces? Why do you want to do it based on index? Why don't you attempt to create only needed geometry in the first place?

Comment: Hello, Andrey, Please reduce your problem to the simplest example that illustrates it, so we know exactly what you mean .. At the moment, "I want to leave the upper and side face of all cubes at once" is a little unclear.. which sides? Do you mean remove all internal faces? etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can't "apply an index"; what you said makes no sense.

anyway, if you want to remove the bottom faces of each cube, or rephrased — "you want to remove the faces point down", then use use normal and a compare node set to *vector* and *direction* set the input vector to `0,0,1` and the angle to `0°`.